# Show selected NUMBERS in bootstrap multi-select dropdown instead of checkbox value

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have Bootstrap Multi-select dropdown and the code is:

```
<select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="one">test value for one</option>
    <option value="two">test value for two</option>
    <option value="three">test value for three</option>
    <option value="four">test value for four</option>
</select>
```

whenever i select from 1 to 3 its showing the selected value. After selecting the fourth checkbox in dropdown it start displaying "4 Selected". the problem is i need to fix the width of the dropdown, so that if i select one, i need to display 1 Selected instead of the first checkbox value. How can i achieve that.

Tried this also but i didnt find what exactly i need. http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/ then try following code...

[DEMO LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/4xbEe/1/)

**JS:**

```
$('#example').multiselect({
     buttonWidth: '500px',
     buttonText: function (options) {
         if (options.length == 0) {
             return 'None selected <b class="caret"></b>';
         } else {
             var selected = 0;
             options.each(function () {
                 selected += 1;
             });
             return selected +  ' Selected  <b class="caret"></b>';
         }
     }
 });
```

**HTML:**

```
<select id="example" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The above demo link works perfect, but i need to trigger 1 more http request(Javascript to link in Head section) only for that dropdown, if anything can be done using only BOOTSRAP js file would be great.

Comment: You are right Nikhil, i missed and i m sorry. And 1 more thing, i added your code and still i am getting the same format instead of 1,2,3 selected. have taken "bootstrap-multiselect.js" and "bootstrap-multiselect.css" from the site. Any suggestion?

Comment: it should be work fine..check demo fiddle...verify your code with code present in demo fiddle..

Comment: Yes Nikhil, The problem is conflict with JQuery version. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes Nikhil, But used an alternative way like how you did with javascript. Have changed from "if (options.length > 3)" to "if (options.length > 0)" in "bootstrap-multiselect.js" file in line number 67. Now if i select one option also started displaying "1 selected". So i am fine with this solution. Thanks for your guidance which made me to look into ".js" file. :)

Comment: You don't need to change it in core "bootstrap-multiselect.js" file, you use above js code to do the same.